# Android load animated SVG via url dynamically using native kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, svg, native

Is there a friendly way of loading this dynamically? Wherein for example I can just do:

```
imageView.loadUrl("https://....../file.svg")
```

Wherein file.svg should be an animated SVG.

What I have tried so far:

- Using coil-kt https://github.com/coil-kt/coil it properly loads svg, but when it comes to animated SVG it doesn't really animate and is just on static I guess the final frame.
- AnimatedVectorDrawable as local asset / resource file, but I would want the dynamic capability wherein I'll just fetch the animated SVGs.
- WebView but it doesn't look good and won't have a proper scaling

Any leads would be appreciated, otherwise I'll have to make my own parser to achieve this.

Comment: I don't have any experience with animated SVGs, but a popular way of showing vector animations is Lottie.

Comment: Hi @momvart forgot to place this one, but I've also tried utilizing Lottie but for local asset / resource file only, I'm not sure if its convenient to be loaded dynamically and I believe lottie files are rendered as .json instead of .svg